# How to implement DSR protocol in ns2 simulator in ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, routes, tcl, ns2

The title of our project is Artificial Immune System for routing protocol (DSR) in MANET.

In this project, our aim is to detect a misbehaving node in the MANET.

We are familiar with TCL and we want to know how to implement DSR in ns2 simulator in Ubuntu.

What I should do next, or where i should search next, or what i should read next, do care to help, even a simple link would be appreciable.

Comment: Look at http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/ and see if it answers your question, particularly the part `new protocol for ns`

Answer (score 4):

For DSR protocol implementation you  no need to do anything, because it's already available in all ns2 versions,you can use below line in TCL script to use DSR protocol.

```
$ns node-config  -adhocRouting DSR \
```

for malicious node implementation refer below link

http://elmurod.net/en/index.php/archives/196

here they have implemented malicious (misbehavior) node in AODV. do the same thing for DSR.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please guide us about how to add attack(eg. blackhole) in tcl script.

Answer (score 0):

I also started working on DSR. Here what i found that to understand any inbuilt protocol must have to go through this files. it is also a flow of creating/cloning of any protocol in ns 2.35.

1. ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\common\packet.h
2. ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\trace\cmu-trace.h
3. ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\trace\cmu-trace.cc
4. ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\tcl\lib\ns-packet.tcl
5. ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\tcl\lib\ns-lib.tcl
6. ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\queue\priqueue.cc
7. ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\Makefile
8. ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\tcl\lib\ns-agent.tcl
9. ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\tcl\lib\ns-mobilenode.tc
10. ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\queue\rtqueue.cc
11. ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\routing\rtable.h
12. ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\wpan\p802_15_4nam.cc
13. ns-allinone-2.35\dei80211mr-1.1.4\src\InitTCL.cc
14. .h and .cc file

but still **DSR** is an optional case .may be i'll comment again in future with more information.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this  code it's work for me fine

```
#===================================
#     Simulation parameters setup
#===================================
Phy/WirelessPhy set bandwidth_ 10Mb        ;#Data Rate
Mac/802_11 set dataRate_ 10Mb              ;#Rate for Data Frames
set val(chan)   Channel/WirelessChannel    ;# channel type
set val(prop)   Propagation/TwoRayGround   ;# radio-propagation model
set val(netif)  Phy/WirelessPhy            ;# network interface type
set val(mac)    Mac/802_11                 ;# MAC type
set val(ifq)    Queue/DropTail/PriQueue    ;# interface queue type
set val(ll)     LL                         ;# link layer type
set val(ant)    Antenna/OmniAntenna        ;# antenna model
set val(ifqlen) 50                         ;# max packet in ifq
set val(nn)     25                         ;# number of mobilenodes
set val(rp)     DSR                       ;# routing protocol
set val(x)      2146                      ;# X dimension of topography
set val(y)      380                      ;# Y dimension of topography
set val(stop)   10.0                         ;# time of simulation end

#===================================
#        Initialization        
#===================================
#Create a ns simulator
set ns [new Simulator]

#Setup topography object
set topo       [new Topography]
$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)
create-god $val(nn)

#Open the NS trace file
set tracefile [open outm.tr w]
$ns trace-all $tracefile

#Open the NAM trace file
set namfile [open outm.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $namfile
$ns namtrace-all-wireless $namfile $val(x) $val(y)
set chan [new $val(chan)];#Create wireless channel

#===================================
#     Mobile node parameter setup
#===================================
$ns node-config -adhocRouting  $val(rp) \
                -llType        $val(ll) \
                -macType       $val(mac) \
                -ifqType       $val(ifq) \
                -ifqLen        $val(ifqlen) \
                -antType       $val(ant) \
                -propType      $val(prop) \
                -phyType       $val(netif) \
                -channel       $chan \
                -topoInstance  $topo \
                -agentTrace    ON \
                -routerTrace   ON \
                -macTrace      ON \
                -movementTrace ON

#===================================
#        Nodes Definition        
#===================================
#Create  nodes
set n0 [$ns node]
$n0 set X_ 573
$n0 set Y_ 357
$n0 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n0 20
set n1 [$ns node]
$n1 set X_ 227
$n1 set Y_ 294
$n1 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n1 20
set n2 [$ns node]
$n2 set X_ 103
$n2 set Y_ 109
$n2 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n2 20
set n3 [$ns node]
$n3 set X_ 882
$n3 set Y_ 112
$n3 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n3 20
set n4 [$ns node]
$n4 set X_ 739
$n4 set Y_ 46
$n4 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n4 20
set n5 [$ns node]
$n5 set X_ 830
$n5 set Y_ -68
$n5 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n5 20
set n6 [$ns node]
$n6 set X_ 905
$n6 set Y_ 336
$n6 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n6 20
set n7 [$ns node]
$n7 set X_ 161
$n7 set Y_ 20
$n7 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n7 20
set n8 [$ns node]
$n8 set X_ 1187
$n8 set Y_ 99
$n8 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n8 20
set n9 [$ns node]
$n9 set X_ 934
$n9 set Y_ -79
$n9 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n9 20
set n10 [$ns node]
$n10 set X_ 416
$n10 set Y_ 120
$n10 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n10 20
set n11 [$ns node]
$n11 set X_ 601
$n11 set Y_ 151
$n11 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n11 20
set n12 [$ns node]
$n12 set X_ 354
$n12 set Y_ 419
$n12 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n12 20
set n13 [$ns node]
$n13 set X_ 1020
$n13 set Y_ 199
$n13 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n13 20
set n14 [$ns node]
$n14 set X_ 513
$n14 set Y_ -54
$n14 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n14 20
set n15 [$ns node]
$n15 set X_ 1019
$n15 set Y_ -17
$n15 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n15 20
set n16 [$ns node]
$n16 set X_ 351
$n16 set Y_ -184
$n16 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n16 20
set n17 [$ns node]
$n17 set X_ 54
$n17 set Y_ -84
$n17 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n17 20
set n18 [$ns node]
$n18 set X_ 278
$n18 set Y_ 267
$n18 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n18 20
set n19 [$ns node]
$n19 set X_ 319
$n19 set Y_ -13
$n19 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n19 20
set n20 [$ns node]
$n20 set X_ 768
$n20 set Y_ -156
$n20 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n20 20
set n21 [$ns node]
$n21 set X_ 962
$n21 set Y_ 198
$n21 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n21 20
set n22 [$ns node]
$n22 set X_ 747
$n22 set Y_ 293
$n22 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n22 20
set n23 [$ns node]
$n23 set X_ 589
$n23 set Y_ -56
$n23 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n23 20
set n24 [$ns node]
$n24 set X_ 627
$n24 set Y_ -225
$n24 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n24 20


#===================================
#        Generate movement          
#===================================

$ns at 0.3 " $n8 setdest 750 55 50 " 
$ns at 0.5 " $n15 setdest 739 46 80 " 
$ns at 0.4 " $n16 setdest 742 280 50 " 
$ns at 0.2 " $n17 setdest 720 170 80 " 
$ns at 0.2 " $n23 setdest 450 144 50 " 

#===================================
#        Agents Definition        
#===================================
#Setup a UDP connection
set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]
$ns attach-agent $n0 $udp0
set null1 [new Agent/Null]
$ns attach-agent $n20 $null1
$ns connect $udp0 $null1
$udp0 set packetSize_ 1500

#===================================
#        Applications Definition        
#===================================
#Setup a CBR Application over UDP connection
set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr0 attach-agent $udp0
$cbr0 set packetSize_ 1000
$cbr0 set rate_ 1.0Mb
$cbr0 set random_ null

$ns at 1.0 "$cbr0 start"
$ns at 5.0 "$cbr0 stop"

#===================================
#        Termination        
#===================================
#Define a 'finish' procedure
proc finish {} {
    global ns tracefile namfile
    $ns flush-trace
    close $tracefile
    close $namfile
    exec nam out.nam &
    exit 0
}               


for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} { incr i } {
    $ns at $val(stop) "\$n$i reset"
}
# malicious node add
$ns at 0.5 "[$n11 set ragent_] hacker"
#$ns at 0.4 "[$n7 set ragent_] hacker 99"
#$ns at 0.4 "[$n4 set ragent_] hacker 99"

$ns at $val(stop) "$ns nam-end-wireless $val(stop)"
$ns at $val(stop) "finish"
$ns at $val(stop) "puts \"done\" ; $ns halt"
$ns run
```